# What is the usage of nun auch wieder?

Tags: word-usage

Can someone explain the usage of "nun auch wieder" to me? It appears to be synonymous with jetzt or nun, but used differently, frequently as "nun auch wieder nicht".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends. "Nun", "auch" and "wieder" of course have their own meaning, and these can of course be combined.

For example, in a video conference:

> A: Ich muss kurz weg, ich komme gleich wieder.
> *(a few minutes later)*
> A: Ich bin **nun auch wieder** da. *(I'm back **again now**, **too**.)*

However, that's probably not what you meant. "Nun auch wieder nicht" is  one of the staple idioms of differentiated discussion in spoken German. It's  frequently used to express that **something went too far** in a (originally good) direction and is therefore rejected. As you stated, it's most often used with "nicht", but it can also be used with other expressions of rejection.

Examples:

> Gast: Was kostet eine Flasche Champagner?
> Kellner: 200 €
> Gast: Oh, so viel möchte ich **nun auch wieder nicht** ausgeben.
> *Or, without "nicht" (less idiomatic)*: Oh, das ist mir **nun auch wieder** zu teuer.

(The patron was willing to spend money for a bottle of Champagne, but not as much as 200 €.)

*Wieder* is used in the sense of *widerum* here, *auch* and *nun* are not used in the sense of "also" and "now", but as particles. I think it's best to learn "nun auch wieder nicht" as an idiom, it's hard to even explain the role of "nun" and "auch" based on what you would find in a dictionary about their use.

More examples for typical uses:

> A: Anton verwöhnt seine Tochter wieder.
> B: Er ist einfach ein schlechter Vater, er lässt alles zu, was sie möchte.
> A: Das kann man **nun auch wieder nicht** sagen! Übertreib doch nicht gleich so!

(B jumped to conclusions and generalized too much for the taste of A.)

> Wir haben in unserem Forum zwar sehr liberale Regeln, aber *alles* ist **nun auch wieder nicht** erlaubt.

(They have permissive rules in their forum in general, but that doesn't go so far that *everything* is permissible.)